# if statement gets stuck at else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a menu appear and disappear by clicking on the same word.
I just started learning these languages. But I think I'm making some progress.
After reading a lot on here and other sources online I figured out this:

```
var main = function() {

if($('.menu').css('top') == '-65px') {    
    $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({top: '10px'}, 400);
        $('.content').animate({top: '10px'}, 400);
    });
}

else {
    $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
        $('.menu').animate({top: '-65px'}, 400);
        $('.content').animate({top: '-65px'}, 400);
    });
}  
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

So far I'm able to make the menu appear but not disappear.

Who can help me?

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS to the question.

Answer (score 5):

You're checking the status of the menu only once, not on each click. Turn things inside out:

```
var main = function() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {

    if ($('.menu').css('top') == '-65px') {    
      $('.menu').animate({top: '10px'}, 400);
      $('.content').animate({top: '10px'}, 400);
    } 
    else {
      $('.menu').animate({top: '-65px'}, 400);
      $('.content').animate({top: '-65px'}, 400);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Using `.click()` is problematic since it doesn't persist if the target is modified in DOM manipulation - you should get in the habit of using `.on('click', ...)` instead.

Comment: True (although `.on()` is needlessly expensive if the target *won't* be modified). Either way, tangential to the problem at hand.

Comment: Yip, seeing it like this I understand why it didn't work. Thank you so much :)!

Comment: True, although not really that expensive, and I thought I would give the OP a pointer for when he runs into the problem (as he will). As you said, tangential to the problem at hand and that's why I upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the position of the menu at the time of binding event, so there will always be one or the other event handler that will be bound, and it won't change when the event is handled.

Use one event handler instead, and check the position when the event happens:

```
$('.icon-menu').click(function() {
  if($('.menu').css('top') == '-65px') {    
    $('.menu').animate({top: '10px'}, 400);
    $('.content').animate({top: '10px'}, 400);
  } else {
    $('.menu').animate({top: '-65px'}, 400);
    $('.content').animate({top: '-65px'}, 400);
  }
});
```